# IOT: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Tags: windows-10-iot-core, windowsiot

I'm trying to run my first IoT on my Raspberry Pi 3.

But using this code ....

```
public void StartServer()
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        listener = new StreamSocketListener();
        listener.Control.KeepAlive = true;
        listener.Control.NoDelay = true;
        await listener.BindServiceNameAsync(port.ToString());             
    });
}
```

I get this error at BindServiceNameAsync...

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
WinRT information: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) 
                   is normally permitted.
```

In appmanifest I have checked "Internet (Client & Server)".

Any idea why I get this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the port that you are trying to use is already being used by another process. Try a different port.